# Why does the comparision between two positions in an array is wrong if one position value's isn't 1?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, comparison, cycle

I'm starting to learn Javascript and i'm developing a simple code that alerts you which number is the bigger one, but i don't know why does the comparision between the position 0 and 1 always equals to position 0 being bigger if it's value isnt 1, for example if the position 0 = 5 and the position 1 = 10 the result is that the position 0 is the bigger one, but if the position 0 = 1 and the position 1 = anything bigger than 1 the result is that the position 1 is the bigger one. I don't know why it only happens with the comparision between the positions 0 and 1 and not with the comparision between 1 and 2.

```
var maths = document.getElementById('nMaths');
var language = document.getElementById('nLanguage');
var history = document.getElementById('nHistory');
var numNotes = [maths.value,language.value,history.value];
var aux;
var biggest;
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if (numNotes[i] < numNotes[i+1]){
        aux = numNotes[i];
        numNotes[i] = numNotes[i+1];
        numNotes[i+1] = aux;
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if (numNotes[i] < numNotes[i+1]){
        aux = numNotas[i];
        numNotes[i] = numNotes[i+1];
        numNotes[i+1] = aux;
     }
}
alert(numNotes[0]);
alert(numNotes[1]);
alert(numNotes[2]);
biggest = "The biggest note is " + numNotes[0];
alert(biggest);
```

Comment: You need to parse the `values` to using `parseInt`. By default the `values` obtained from `dom` `elements` is of type `string`.

Comment: Where do i need to parse the values? I tried parsing them here: var numNotes = [parseInt(maths),parseInt(language),parseInt(history)]; but when i try to see what is the value from this variable it says [object HTMLInputElement], where should i parse the variables? Thnx for your answer.

Comment: you need to parse the values. For example: `parseInt(maths.value)`

Comment: It was that! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo, on the line

```
aux = numNotas[i];
```

it should be

```
aux = numNotes[i]; //changed 'a' for an 'e'
```

Comment: It's not because of that, i translated the code because it was written in spanish and forgot to change that a to an e, haah. I just edited it. Anyway thnx for your answer.